# How drift current is independent of bias voltage in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductors

The equation J=nqv where n is a concentration of electrons or holes,v is drift velocity.also, v=uE where u-mobility, E is an electric field.SO as bias voltage increases, in turn, increases the Electric field and then results in an increase in Current Density.So how it is possible that the drift current is independent of bias voltage.

[image]

Comment: Who said it was independent?  There are two currents in semiconductors, drift and diffusion.  The diffusion current depends on the doping concentration and is independent of the bias.

Answer (score 1):

The drift current essentially depends only on the rate of generation of the minority carriers. It is because the minority carriers are generated much slower than they are swept due to the field. Had the generation rate been higher than the speed at which they are swept due to the field, the electric field strength would have affected the magnitude of drift current. 
Conclusion: drift current is independent of bias unlike diffusion current

Answer (score 0):

The equation of drift current density J = nqv actually shows implicitly that drift current Density depends on voltage!!

v which is the drift velocity depends on the electric field

v = u*E where u is the electron(or hole) mobility.

Since the electric field E = V/d.Depends on voltage,Then the drift current density Depends on voltage through the electric field dependence.

Answer (score 0):

The drift velocity (\$v_d\$) is a function of the electric field (\$E\$). However, the equation you provide,

$$
v_d = \mu E
$$

is a simplification that is only valid for low electric fields. At high electric fields, interactions with optical phonons cause the drift velocity to approach the "saturation velocity" \$v_s\$

$$
v_s = \sqrt{\frac{8E_p}{3\pi m_0}} \approx 10^7 \text{cm/s (Si and Ge)}
$$

Where \$E_p\$ is the optical-phonon energy for the material and \$m_0\$ is the mass of an electron.